# Legal questions

Tags: discussion

How should we deal with questions about legality?

[Can I sell my Homebrew in the UK](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2816/can-i-sell-my-homebrew-in-the-uk)

Answer (score 3):

Consider voting to close them using the "Too Localized" reason.

Comment: At first I thought this answer was not really helpful, since it only dealt with the example given, and not the underlying question. But then I thought more, and since issues of legality are dependent on the laws of your locality, I agree: all questions about the legality of something are 'too localized'.

Answer (score 0):

The question should be phrased generic to any region, but as long as it is a legitimate question within the realm of home brewing, it should be accepted.  The best answer would then be one that answers the question for a variety of locations.  http://bicycles.stackexchange.com does this without issue, and it results in good answers to good questions.  Legal issues are very important in cycling and certain in alcohol production.