# Can we decide which legal questions are on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Before marking as a dupe of [this](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/legal-questions), my questions is more of a request for consistency.

[This comment](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12617/how-do-i-legally-sell-my-home-brew-in-the-uk#comment15774_12617) made me look up other questions about the legality of selling homebrew. It seems sometimes they get [closed as off-topic](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/q/12617/3925), and sometimes they get [voted up](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/q/4780/3925) and [answered](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/q/3186/3925).

If we do decide they are off topic, they should all be closed. Or, considering the number of questions about it, the closed questions should be re-opened. Can we just make up our minds?

Answer (score 3):

The way I see it, most legal questions should be off topic. The site should feature expert advice on beer and brewing, not legal advice.

It's similar to an issue on my home stack (cooking) where people constantly ask questions about nutrition. Health related questions are off topic on that stack because it is a community of expert cooks and cooking enthusiasts, not doctors and dietitians.

Either way, a stack needs consensus and the rules need to be enforced.